# $("#id").val(); -- vs -- $('#id').val(); getting value form a Modal undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, modal-dialog, undefined

Recently, I had an issue and could not figure out why I was getting undefined on a selector to retrieve a name from `Div tag` with `id=GetNameID` in a pop-up modal (bootstrap 3.x).

Before you look at the answer, you might want to take a guess which of the two forms returns the value correctly...

While I am no JS guru, (finally after significant amounts of testing) I finally found that *replacing it with a single quote worked in getting the name value* as opposed to the double quotes listed in Jquery reference. I have pasted both references in the link to reference the selectors syntax.

[`$("#GetNameID").val();`](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) From Jquery site  [`$('#GetNameID').val();`](http://codylindley.com/jqueryselectors/) From CodeLindey

1. Can someone tell me why does single quote work here in the *modal* and
   not double quote? is it the modal that makes it unique?
2. What is the correct way to get the value using jquery syntax? For a Modal and Regular Page

Comment: there is no difference on javascript strings as long as opening and closing quotes match and aren't interrupted by an unescaped same type quote. Please provide demo that replicates what you are suggesting. Modal vs non modal is irrelevant...it's all in the same DOM

Comment: What is wrong is that you can't use `val()` on a `<div>` , it is used to get `value` from form control elements

Comment: As charlietfl mentions, you probably want `$('#GetNameID').html();`

Answer (score 0):

Single and double quotes *are* interchangeable in JavaScript for string literals, so depending on where your got you code from, it is possible you actually had the "other" double quotes (e.g. the Unicode pair normally used for word processors).

e.g. `“ ”` instead of `" "`

That would definitely have caused an error as they are invalid for delimiting a JavaScript string literal.

The other point mentioned in comments is that `val()` on a `div` will not return the content. It will return an empty string.

Use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to get the text value (sans any elements), or [.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/) to get the raw inner HTML.

See this example for the variations:

```
<div id="test"><span>My </span>value</div>

alert($('#test').val());   // "" (empty string)
alert($('#test').text());  // "My Value"
alert($('#test').html());  // "<span>My </span>value"
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/cookugt6/

Note: I encourage the use of single quotes for string constants in JavaScript/jQuery, so that double-quotes are available for creating literal HTML attributes (while either quotes are acceptable to all browsers, tools seem to work better with double-quotes).